# Passing inputs to a new intent

Tags: android, android-intent

hello there i'm a new beginner in android development. I tried several times to figure out my issue  but i couldn't please help me.I created a simple login screen once the user enters the username and password I simply want to display it in the next activity. I used putExtra and getExtra but the values are null all the time.
This is my code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Data1.this , Data2.class);
            i.putExtra("uname",username.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pass",password.getText().toString());
            Log.d("username",username.getText().toString());
            Log.d("password",password.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);

 data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

     Intent i = this.getIntent();
     u = i.getStringExtra("username");
     p = i.getStringExtra("password");

     data.setText(u+" Successfully logged in User Name - "+ u + " Password - "+ p);
```

Comment: Always post the error log in these situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've Passed the Data to the next Intent Correctly using PutExtra but in the new intent when you've used getStringExtra you've used another String variable which is completely different from what you've passed.Try this example it should work.You should use i.getStringExtra("uname"); and i.getStringExtra("pass"); instead of what you have passed.

public class Data1 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText username;
EditText password;
Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data1);

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edusername);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edpassword);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Data1.this , Data2.class);
            i.putExtra("uname",username.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("pass",password.getText().toString());
            Log.d("username",username.getText().toString());
            Log.d("password",password.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

public class Data2 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView data;
String u;
String p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data2);

    data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
   // Intent i = getIntent();
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
     u = i.getStringExtra("uname");
     p = i.getStringExtra("pass");



    data.setText(u+" Successfully logged in User Name - "+ u + " Password - "+ p);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You a passing the value using

```
i.putExtra("uname",username.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("pass",password.getText().toString());
```

and getting value using

```
u = i.getStringExtra("username");
p = i.getStringExtra("password");
```

here you must be use same key as you passed in intent so you have to use "uname" instead of "username" and "pass" instead of "password"..

example : 
FirstActivity.java

`i.putExtra("key", "value");`

secondActivity.java

```
i.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null values because strings are not same in put and get method.And values are always stored in same key.So change your code in get method like as-

```
 Intent i = this.getIntent();
 u = i.getStringExtra("uname");
 p = i.getStringExtra("pass");`
```